# jade template won't render with ui-router dynamic param

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I'm using express 4 to render jade templates for angular. When I try and route with a dynamic parameter on the client, my routes don't match so express sends `layout.jade` twice.

[image]

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/home',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('about', {
            // works fine
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'views/about'
        })
        .state('post', {
            url: '/post/{id}',
            // view does not render
            templateUrl: 'views/post',
            controller: 'PostCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

For when I hit `http://localhost:3000/post/0` the request goes out to `Request URL:http://localhost:3000/post/views/post` which does not match anything.

I want to render `public/views/post.jade` when hitting `/post/{id}`

These is the express 4 routes and config:

```
app.set('views', path.join(config.rootPath, '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(config.rootPath, 'public')));

app.get('/views/:name', function(req, res){
   res.render('../public/views/' + req.params.name);
})

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('layout');
});
```

**Note**
If I change the post state to use template:

```
  .state('post', {
        url: '/post/{id}',
        template: '<div>{{ post }}</div> is that',
        controller: 'PostCtrl'
  });
```

The template will render fine. The problem is when I use `templateUrl: 'views/post'`

**Update:**

From the home view I can navigate to see `post.jade` with:

`div(ng-repeat='post in posts track by $index')
   a(ui-sref='post({ id:{{ $index }} })') Comments`

That navigates to `views/post` alright, but if I refresh the page I get the same layout-layout error

Answer (score -1):

(I'm assuming `config.rootPath` is the root directory of your project. You should check out http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

So first of all, if you have all of your views in a directory `{config.rootPath}/public/views`, this line:

```
app.set('views', path.join(config.rootPath, '/views'));
```

is basically telling Express to look for your jade files in `{config.rootPath}/views`, which isn't the correct location. Try:

```
app.set('views', path.join(config.rootPath, 'public', 'views'));
```

This will allow you to just specify paths relative to `public/views` whenever you want to render a jade file - so on the angular side of things, if you wanted to render `public/views/post.jade` when hitting `/post/{id}`, it would just be:

```
.state('post', {
    url: '/post/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/post',
    controller: 'PostCtrl'
})
```

and on the backend, loading the views would just look like

```
app.get('/:name', function(req, res){
    res.render(req.params.name);
})
```

(Note: It's not the best idea to have a param as the base of the path. You'd want to have a directory `public/views/partials` for your partials, so instead of `'/:name'` - which would intercept pretty much everything - you'd use `'/partials/:name'` )

Comment: yeah this does not change anything. Tried removing the / but does not help

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? My answer included quite a few changes